# Sql Update query to update a column in an existing table to have unique value which has duplicate values

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an existing table called Script which has many scripts present with unique script Id and non unique script name.And there are many records in this table.
Now as part of my current development i have made script names to be unique.This table gets populated when some body uploads scripts through UI.Now For the already present scripts,there is no restriction on duplicacy of values in script Name column.So it has many duplicate records present.
Now i want to give all the existing script Names, a unique name by adding some suffix.How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
declare @T table (script_id int not null IDENTITY(1,1) primary key,
                 script_name varchar(30) not null)
insert into @T (script_name) values
('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('b'),('a'),('e'),('c'),('b');

;with Ordered as (
    select *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY script_name ORDER by script_id) as rn
    from @T
)
update Ordered set script_name = script_name +
    CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN '_' + CONVERT(varchar(10),rn) ELSE '' END

select * from @T
```

Results:

```
script_id   script_name
----------- ------------------------------
1           a
2           b
3           c
4           d
5           b_2
6           a_2
7           e
8           c_2
9           b_3
```